# Show git log for the current file in Magit 2.1

Tags: magit

In 1.x Magit used to provide `magit-file-log` to list the Git log for the current file.  Unfortunately, this command seems to be gone from Magit 2.1?  How do I list the Git log for the current file now in Magit 2.1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is now `magit-log-buffer-file`.